# Flyway Java-based migration ignored in a mixed migrations folder

Tags: java, flyway

I have sql migrations placed in the recourses folder of the project, but then we needed to create a Java-based migration, which we placed in the same folder:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8XEH.png

For some reason the Java-based migration is completely ignored:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mqkk.png

Can I not mix the two types of migrations together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java-based migrations must be compiled first. For that they must be under src/main/java, instead of of src/main/resources

Comment: I tried moving all of the migrations to src/main/java, but the .sql files were not copied to the target folder on compilation. Do I need two separate folders for each type?

Comment: Nevermind, you're right. That did it ,I just had to clean my tomcat dir. Thanks so much