# Flyway sort sql files with java class

Tags: java, spring, flyway

1. Previously, we added: `V1__XX.sql`, `V2__YY.sql` and `V19_ZZ.sql` sql files to be applied by Flyway.
2. Then we introduced a Java migration class named: `V20_JJ.java`.
3. Now, when we add `V21_NN.sql`, we get ofc `Detected resolved migration not applied to database` error.

Is it possible to put java and sql migrations all in order by name?

(We'd prefer not to use the `ignore missing migrations` or `out of order` features unless they are a last resort)

Comment: As I understand, `V21_NN.sql` is not applied, isn't it? 
Could you check how exactly `V20` migration is named? Version separator should look like "__".
Why do you use "src/main/java/db.migration" instead of "src/main/java/db/migration"?

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain why do you get the error? In case you have migrations `V1`, `V2`... `V20` already applied, you should not get error when adding migration `V21` as it's **in order** and **was not missed**.

It may be just that your `V21_NN.sql` is incorrect.

Comment: I guess flyway first runs sql files(v1,v2,..v19, v21) and then java (v20). Here is the error:
`Validate failed: Detected resolved migration not applied to database: 20`

Comment: @cek that's weird. Mixing `java` and `sql` migrations should work out of the box with correct ordering. Could it be that the [java migration was not compiled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26772770/flyway-java-based-migration-ignored-in-a-mixed-migrations-folder) at the time `V21` was applied?

Comment: nope, java migration located under `src/main/java/db.migration`

Comment: Well anyway, if you remove the `V20` and try to add `V22_something.java` and `V23_something.sql` it should work just fine... in that case I would recommend only clearing your development database, if `V21` was never released to production. Or renaming `V20` to `V22` (with some changes if necessary) otherwise, since database migrations should be "append only".